# ViewController not properly sending over NSURL data to Destination ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, segue

When a user taps a cell, I want `itemURL` to be set to that cells "Item URL" property. Once it does this, it should then send over the `itemURL` in `prepareForSegue` over to `WebViewController`, as I've attempted to do. When I have `WebViewController` `NSLog` the `itemURL` property however, it comes up as null. How can I make sure the value is sent over properly?

**MatchCenterViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "AsyncImageView.h"
#import "SearchViewController.h"
#import "WebViewController.h"



@interface MatchCenterViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *itemSearch;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *imageURLs;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *matchingCategoryCondition;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *matchingCategoryLocation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *matchingCategoryMaxPrice;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *matchingCategoryMinPrice;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *matchCenterArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *searchTerm;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *itemURL;

@end
```

**MatchCenterViewController.m:**

```
#import "MatchCenterViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MatchCenterViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *matchCenter;
@end

@implementation MatchCenterViewController


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.matchCenter = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle];
    self.matchCenter.frame = CGRectMake(0,50,320,self.view.frame.size.height-100);
    _matchCenter.dataSource = self;
    _matchCenter.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.matchCenter];

    _matchCenterArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.matchCenterArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"MatchCenter"
                       withParameters:@{
                                        @"test": @"Hi",
                                        }
                                block:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error) {

                                    if (!error) {
                                        _matchCenterArray = result;
                                        [_matchCenter reloadData];

                                        NSLog(@"Result: '%@'", result);
                                    }
                                }];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return _matchCenterArray.count;
}

//the part where i setup sections and the deleting of said sections

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 21.0f;
}


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 21)];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    _searchTerm = [[[[_matchCenterArray  objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"Top 3"] objectAtIndex:3]objectForKey:@"Search Term"];

    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 0, 250, 21)];
    headerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _searchTerm];
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];


    UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    deleteButton.tag = section;
    deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(300, 2, 17, 17);
    [deleteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"xbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [headerView addSubview:deleteButton];
    return headerView;

}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Initialize cell
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        // if no cell could be dequeued create a new one
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // No cell seperators = clean design
    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // title of the item
    cell.textLabel.text = _matchCenterArray[indexPath.section][@"Top 3"][indexPath.row][@"Title"];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];

    // price of the item
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", _matchCenterArray[indexPath.section][@"Top 3"][indexPath.row][@"Price"]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:127/255.0f blue:31/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    // image of the item
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_matchCenterArray[indexPath.section][@"Top 3"][indexPath.row][@"Image URL"]]];
    [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];

    return cell;

}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 65;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSURL *itemURL = _matchCenterArray[indexPath.section][@"Top 3"][indexPath.row][@"Item URL"];

//    NSLog(@"The url is: '%@'", itemURL);

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"WebViewSegue" sender:self];
}


- (void)deleteButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    // links button
    UIButton *deleteButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    // Define the sections title
    NSString *sectionName = _searchTerm = [[[[_matchCenterArray  objectAtIndex:deleteButton.tag] objectForKey:@"Top 3"] objectAtIndex:3]objectForKey:@"Search Term"];

    // Run delete function with respective section header as parameter
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"deleteFromMatchCenter"
                       withParameters:
                      @{@"searchTerm": sectionName,}
                                block:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {
                                   if (!error) {
                                       [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"MatchCenter"
                                                          withParameters:@{
                                                                           @"test": @"Hi",
                                                                           }
                                                                   block:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error) {

                                                                       if (!error) {
                                                                           _matchCenterArray = result;
                                                                           [_matchCenter reloadData];

                                                                           NSLog(@"Result: '%@'", result);
                                                                       }
                                                                   }];

                                   }
                                }];
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



 #pragma mark - Navigation

 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {


     WebViewController *controller = (WebViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
     controller.itemURL = self.itemURL;


 }


@end
```

**WebViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MatchCenterViewController.h"

@interface WebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *itemURL;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView;

@end
```

**WebViewController.m:**

```
#import "WebViewController.h"

@interface WebViewController ()

@end

@implementation WebViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"The url is: '%@'", _itemURL);

//    _myWebView=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
//    _myWebView.delegate=self;
//    [self.view addSubview:_myWebView];

    self.myWebView.delegate = self;

    //////////
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:_itemURL];
    //4
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    //5
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil) [self.myWebView loadRequest:request];
         else if (error != nil) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];

    [self.myWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    //////





    //[self.myWebView loadRequest:request];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: When asking a question, try to post as little code as possible to make the reading of the question faster and therefore make readers' life easier. Here, you could have post only the methods lead up to the `WebViewController` (`didSelectRowFroIndexPath:` and `prepareForSegue:`)

Comment: Also you could remove all the empty / default template methods if you don't change them, they are not doing anything for you leaving them in.

Comment: @TomAhh right, sorry about that. I originally wanted to, but I wasn't sure if any of it might be important to keep. I'll keep it in mind for next time.

Comment: @Ghobs you can still edit your question now so that future readers wont be confused ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `didSelectRowForIndexPath:` instead of

```
NSURL *itemURL = _matchCenterArray[indexPath.section][@"Top 3"][indexPath.row][@"Item URL"];
```

use

```
self.itemURL = _matchCenterArray[indexPath.section][@"Top 3"][indexPath.row][@"Item URL"];
```